# how to use simple alert message using javascript in asp.net mvc with razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a problem to make alert message using javascript in asp.net mvc, can someone tell me and give me some example or reference to `make simple alert message in asp.net mvc with razor...`

Comment: On this site, people are generally interested in seeing that you have tried something, or attempted to solve the problem in some way. See this article: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/. Could you post some code that you have tried?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

you should use this.

```
  <script>alert('it is alert message')</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

First include `Jquery` reference

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        alert("First Alert Message");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use pure javascript or jquery.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
         alert("you'r message");
        });
     </script>
```